# How to get the Xpath of textarea tag after this div

Tags: xpath

[image]I'm trying to select the element in the textarea tag after the div with the textcontent "Queixa Principal" but I'm not getting it at all I already tried chield and parent Axis like:

```
//*[text() = " Queixa Principal "]/textarea
//*[text() = " Queixa Principal "][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//div[normalize-space(text())='Queixa Principal']/following::textarea[1]
```

It does select the first `textarea` elements after all `div`s which contain the `text()` value "Queixa Principal".

Comment: Wow, it worked like a charm, i didn't even now the normalize-space parameter in xpath it sure will help me in other scenarios thanks a lot! Sorry for taking so long to mark as solved i've kinda used the full xpath as a workaround and forgot the problem LOL

Comment: Glad it was useful for you.